# Hibernate: Difference on Projection(SUM) of two different entities

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have written a sql code to get value of closing stock of an item based on given date.

```
SELECT (SELECT Sum(qtyreceived) 
    FROM   purchaseinvoicedetails pid, 
           purchaseinvoice pi 
    WHERE  itemid_itemid = 1 
           AND pi.piid = pid.pidetails 
           AND pi.pidate < Curdate()) - (SELECT Sum(qtysent) 
                                         FROM   salesinvoicedetails sid, 
                                                salesinvoice si 
                                         WHERE  itemid_itemid = 1 
                                                AND si.siid = sid.siid_siid 
                                                AND si.sidate < Curdate()) 
   AS 
   closingstock
```

It returns closing stock value of an item.

The same I want to achieve using hibernate criteria. 
I am unable to figure out the logic.

Thanks in Advance